# why is this xml layout crashing my app?

Tags: android, xml

This layout is used as the layout for items in a listView. I had a really simple layout, and everything was working fine, but now i have changed it a little and it is crashing my app when it tries to load.. Not sure what im doing wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView android:id="@+id/storeText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|top"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#545454"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
       android:text=">"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="36dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" 
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When u get unusual error all of sudden, best way  is clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Plus won't be a bad idea to quit and restart eclipse.. Never trust eclipse one bit

Comment: And ur most of tags is missing width attribute, which also may cause some problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**When you use android:layout_weight put layout_width="0dip"**

Working code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/storeText"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="right|bottom"
           android:textColor="#000000"
           android:textSize="22dp"
           android:textStyle="bold" />

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/distanceText"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="right|top"
           android:textColor="#545454"
           android:textSize="16dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
       android:text=">"
       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="36dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" 
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `android:layout_width=".."` and `android:layout_height=".."`to all the views:

```
   <TextView android:id="@+id/storeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right|top"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#545454"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
   android:text=">"
   android:textColor="#000000"
   android:textSize="36dp"
   android:textStyle="bold" 
   android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

every element you gave android_layout_weight you didn't give a width. If you gave this weight so the element takes a certain space you should give the layout
android:layout_width="0"
so it takes the weight as width

height and width are required tags for every element

Answer (score 0):

you have missed some layout width and layout height attributes. 
i have added in the all items.

Please use the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="8"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp">

   <TextView android:id="@+id/priceText"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView android:id="@+id/storeText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|bottom"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="22dp"

            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/distanceText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right|top"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="#545454"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
       android:text=">"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

       android:textColor="#000000"
       android:textSize="36dp"
       android:textStyle="bold" 
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Since he is using weights, it would be better if he put either width or height as 0dp based on requirement.

Comment: Yes Black Devil you are correct. As per his requirement he can change it.Any way both height and weight attributes should be there in each elements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve here by this layout but there are few mistake in your xml.

1. At various places width and height are missing. Consider adding those.
2. You are adding LinearLayout as parent tag but using RelativeLayout Tags like

   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

   do consider removing those.
3. Use properly combination of `android:layout_weight=""`  and `android:layout_height="" , android:layout_width=""`

Comment if any clarification or help required